# Регулярное выражение по белорускому идентификационному номеру

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как составить регулярное выражение чтобы была проверка на правильность белорусского идентификационного номера?

Пример : `3040979Е028РВ8`

Тоесть - 14 символов, цифры + буквы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^[A-Z0-9]{14}$/
```

незаглавные буквы нужны?
кириллические символы нужны?

Comment: спасибо, работает. только нужно так `^[A-Z0-9]{14}$`

Comment: @Telsystems зависит от контекста (языка) применения

Answer (score 0):

`^[0-9]{7}[A|B|C|K|E|M|H]{1}[0-9]{3}[GB|PB|BA|BI]{2}[0-9]{1}$`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Одиночные символы в квадратных скобках можно перечислить без разделения: `[ABCKEMH]`. Пары символов, которые всегда иду вместе, лучше перечислить в круглых скобках через черту без `{2}`. В квадратных скобках будет реагировать на любое сочетание символов `[|GBPAI]` (черта скорее всего тоже будет считаться допустимым символом). В итоге должно получиться `^[0-9]{7}[ABCKEMH]{1}[0-9]{3}(GB|PB|BA|BI)[0-9]{1}$`